# How to make this form validation script loop through the whole form section before returning?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, loops

I am developing a [patient satisfaction questionnaire](http://www.gezondezorg.org/upt-schaal-tryout.php). I have a form validation script that should check whether one or more items in the A sub-section has been given a score, if on the A main question certain radios are checked. It looks like this at the moment:

```
function countRadiosChecked(chdRds) { 
    var cnt = -1;
    for (i=chdRds.length-1; i>-1; i--) {
        if (chdRds[i].checked)
        {cnt=i; i=-1;}
    }
    if (cnt > -1) return chdRds[cnt].value;
    else return null; /* = the number, not the value of the radio buttons */
}


function checkASection() {
if ((upssForm.A[0].checked == true) || (upssForm.A[1].checked == true) || (upssForm.A[2].checked == true) || (upssForm.A[4].checked == true)) {
    var itemsANamesArray = ['A1a','A1b','A1c','A1d','A1e','A1f','A1g','A2a','A2b','A2c','A2d','A2e','A2f','A2g','A2h','A2i','A2j','A2k','A2l','A2m','A2n','A2o','A2p','A2q','A2r'];
    var thatAName = null;
    var itemsANamesArrayCount = itemsANamesArray.length;
    for (i=0; i<itemsANamesArrayCount; i++) {
        thatAName = itemsANamesArray[i];
        var thatANameGroup = upssForm.elements[thatAName];
        var nrOfRadiosChecked = countRadiosChecked(thatANameGroup);
            if (nrOfRadiosChecked == null)
        {
            alert('No item in the A sub-section has been given a score');
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}
}
```

But the script already gives an alert if on the first item no score has been given, while it should loop through the whole array before alerting, if necessary. How do I that?

Comment: do you want to check for all items in itemsANamesArray  before you exit ?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I want.

Comment: this should work for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    function countRadiosChecked(chdRds) { 
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i=chdRds.length-1; i>-1; i--) {
        if (chdRds[i].checked){
           cnt = 1; 
           break;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}


function checkASection() {
    if ((upssForm.A[0].checked == true) || (upssForm.A[1].checked == true) || (upssForm.A[2].checked == true) || (upssForm.A[4].checked == true)) {
        var itemsANamesArray = ['A1a','A1b','A1c','A1d','A1e','A1f','A1g','A2a','A2b','A2c','A2d','A2e','A2f','A2g','A2h','A2i','A2j','A2k','A2l','A2m','A2n','A2o','A2p','A2q','A2r'];
        var thatAName = null;
        var itemsANamesArrayCount = itemsANamesArray.length;
        var nrOfRadiosChecked =0;
        for (var i=0; i<itemsANamesArrayCount; i++) {
            thatAName = itemsANamesArray[i];
            var thatANameGroup = upssForm.elements[thatAName];
            nrOfRadiosChecked = nrOfRadiosChecked + countRadiosChecked(thatANameGroup);

        }
        if (nrOfRadiosChecked == 0){
            alert('No item in the A sub-section has been given a score');
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: With your edit it now works perfectly! Awesome, I would never have figured that out myself! Thank you very much, Surender, you're the best! :-)

Comment: No problem, you should just try to understand the changes now :)

Comment: Oops, I was a bit too fast. It works essentially, but the script call button keeps having focus after the function has been executed. I put it online for your convenience, see the original post for the link. The button 'Controleer invulling' under the table is the (test) call button.

Comment: Never mind. That focus thing seemingly is an imperfection of IE and FF in the rendering of breaking loop scripts, since Chrome and Saf don't have it. The same thing happens at this simple script: w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_break. Also, I'm not getting any error reports from Firebug. Finally, a simple `blur(this)` in the onclick attribute solved it. So, you're still the best. :-)

Comment: Things are usually pretty simple, need a little googling and you would find all the answers :)